# Книга WPF 4 Unleashed Adam Nathan

Tags: wpf, книги

Здравствуйте! 
Видел ли кто или, хотя бы, знает про существование данной книги в русском переводе?
Еще лучше если в электронном виде. Спасибо!

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что беспокойство людей, возможно встречавших искомую книгу, не соответствует тематике StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Вот](http://www.books.ru/books/wpf-4-podrobnoe-rukovodstvo-827249/) нашел пишут что отличный перевод